# django elastic search giving TransportError 400 for model id large digit search

Tags: elasticsearch, django-rest-framework

I am getting this error while I am searching large digit ,where my model has only interger field

[image: go]

```
class PurchaseDocument(DocType):
        status = fields.IntegerField()
        purchase_order_status = fields.IntegerField()
        organization = fields.ObjectField(properties={
            'pk': fields.IntegerField()
        })
        sales_return = fields.ObjectField(
            properties={
                'pk': fields.IntegerField()
            }
        )

    class Meta:
            model = Purchase
            fields = [
                'id',
                'remarks',
                'vouchar_no'
            ]

            rebuild_from_value_list = True
            related_models = [Purchase, Transaction, TransactionPurchase]
```

I have purchase model like this-

```
class Purchase(model.Models):
  //something
```

Comment: It would be nice to see what the underlying error is. Can you check in your Elasticsearch server logs?

Comment: ERROR - Sentry responded with an API error: APIError(Invalid project_id: u'1209001')

Comment: That's not what I'm looking for. Your Elasticsearch server logs is located in `/var/log/elasticsearch`